# Multiple field foreign key in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have two models in django with definitions below.
CreativeStatus model :

```
class RtbdCreativeStatus(models.Model):
    creative_id = models.CharField(max_length=500, primary_key=True)
    advertiser_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    exposure_level = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField()
    modified_by = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class RtbdCreative(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    advertiser_id = models.ForeignKey(RtbdCreativeStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creative_id = models.ForeignKey(RtbdCreativeStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country_id = models.IntegerField()
    adm = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    sample_url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    landing_page = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    html = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    creative_attributes = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    advertiser_domains = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
    creative_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    demand_source_type_id = models.IntegerField()
    revalidate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

(creative_id, advertiser_id ) combination is unique in my CreativeStatus table . I want that combination to be my foreign key for Creative table. I tried adding it but i get this error .[image: Screenshot of the error in django]

1)How do i achieve this join with two key combination as my foreign key .

2)What should be my query to fetch all the creatives with their status from CreativeStatus table .

**UPDATE 1**

on reading the answers below , i updated my model as mentioned below :

```
class RtbdCreative(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    advertiser_id = models.ForeignKey(RtbdCreativeStatus, to_field='advertiser_id', related_name='advertiser', db_column='advertiser_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creative_id = models.ForeignKey(RtbdCreativeStatus, to_field='creative_id', related_name='creative', db_column='creative_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country_id = models.IntegerField()
    adm = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    sample_url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    landing_page = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    html = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    creative_attributes = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    advertiser_domains = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
    creative_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    demand_source_type_id = models.IntegerField()
    revalidate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now i am getting this error[image] . I have combination of advertiser_id , craetive_id as unique . But django expects both to be unique. What can i do to make it work ?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your second question, `CreativeStatus` table and `Creative` table are not related. But if `RtdbCreativeStatus` table and `CreativeStatus` are any way related, you should post the respective models, for further questions..

Comment: @FazilZaid RtbdCreative table is Creative table above , i am planning to chnage the name , the screenshot is a bit old. I just want to know the query to access both the tables after join in django

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in ERRROS, you need to add related_name as argument, when you want to add more than one foreign key for same Model.

```
class Creative(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    advertiser_id = models.ForeignKey(RtbdCreativeStatus,
                                      related_name="Advertiser", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creative_id = models.ForeignKey(RtbdCreativeStatus,
                                    related_name="Creative",
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country_id = models.IntegerField()
    adm = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    sample_url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    landing_page = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    html = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    creative_attributes = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(
        max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    advertiser_domains = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
    creative_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    demand_source_type_id = models.IntegerField()
    revalidate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: after updating the model as suggested by you , I am getting a new error . I don't have both the fields to be unique . I have their combination  unique .  How can i get this to work ?

Answer (score 2):

I just saw a parameter as `to_fields` for **models.ForeignObject**, superclass of **models.ForeignKey**. It might be used in this case for defining foreign key for composite primary key or unique keys.

```
    advertiser_creative_id = models.ForeignObject(RtbdCreativeStatus, to_fields=['advertiser_id', 'creative_id'], related_name='abc', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

There is a `from_fields` parameter as well. It can be used to map the fields with `to_fields`.
Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/fields/related/

Answer (score 0):

When you add multiple ForeignKeys towards same table, you should override the `related_name` option of your fields, so that the fields could be distinguished easily.

You could implement a custom validation for checking uniqueness of the `creative_id` and `advertiser_id`,

```
class Creative(models.Model):
    advertiser_id = models.ForeignKey(CreativeStatus,
                                  related_name="advertisers")
    creative_id = models.ForeignKey(CreativeStatus,
                                related_name="creatives")

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        if not data['advertiser_id'] == data['creative_id']:
            raise ValidationError("Unique Constraint failed {}, {}".format(self.advertiser_id, self.creative_id))
        return data
```

You could query your creatives from `CreativeStatus` using the related name.

```
creative_status_obj = CreativeStatus.objects.get(pk=some_pk)#or any query.
#All creatives of the given object can be queried using reverse relation.
creatives = creative_status_obj.creatives.all()
```